# MATLAB image() is rotated after hold on

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, vlfeat

I'm printing an image like this :

```
img = imread('path/to/image.jpg');
image(img);
```

this is fine, but when I do

```
img = imread('path/to/image.jpg');
hold on;
image(img);
```

image is rotated 180 degrees. Any ideas why, and how to fix this ?

Why am I doing `hold on` ?  Because I'm trying to draw something else on the picture.

Thanks for any help!

### The Exact Problem

Image was rotated 180 degrees around center point, **and then another** 180 degrees around y axis.

### The Answer :

Thanks to @lennon310, I have updated my code to this :

```
img = imread(filename);
img = flipdim(img,1);
do_vlfeat_things(img);
hold on;
image(img);
```

Now it works correctly.

Comment: The 180 degrees rotation comes from the different conventions in coordinates for images (first is left->right) to arrays (first is top down) in Matlab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rows of an image are stored from top to bottom, you may use

```
hold on,image([1 size(img,1)],[size(img,2) 1],img)
```

to reverse the image along y-axis.

To reverse the loaded matrix at the beginning, use (row reverse)

```
img1 = flipdim(img,1);
```

Comment: This works. Thanks ! However, the VLFeat function still operates on the reversed image.. How can I rotate the image 180 degrees and store it in the img variable ?

Comment: Thanks again. And one more detail, now I'm recognizing that my image is rotated as follows : 180 degree around center point , AND 180 degree around y axis. What do you suggest for this case? Sorry for the late update but I didn't notice this before. **Edit** Oh wait, your last solution (flipdim) also works for this. I'm updating the question to add the final solution. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Display the image first, then use hold:

```
image(img);
hold on;
```

Comment: Or simply flip the axis: `set(gca,'ydir','reverse')`.